# Is $y^2$ even function??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, even-and-odd-functions

the solution of this problem says that since $y^2$ is an even function and so is $cosx-1$ therefore $y'$ is an even function which implies $y$ is odd function and from there on the solution builds up

I can not understand how is $y(x)^2$ even??

here is the full solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI3UBYJ21iw&t=98s

[image]

---

---

---

I am getting more confused now here is one more example where $y^2$ is taken to be even

this is the solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnqOCpqUebQ
[image]

what's going on???

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why $y^2$ is even, either.

Comment: Generally, it would be better to include the part of the material you're asking about.

Comment: I agree - not every "squared function" is even, so some other information must be being used. The condition $y(0)=0$ seems important.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI3UBYJ21iw&t=98s this guys says y^2 is even

Comment: The simple answer is "That guy is wrong".  There're a lot of channels like that and not a whole lot of quality control.

Comment: It seems that the answerer confused $y^2$ as a function of $y$ (which is obviously even) and $y(x)^2$, a function of $x$, which as others have pointed out, needs not to be even or odd. Actually, $y(x)^2$ even implies that $y(-x)=\epsilon(x) y(x)$ with $\epsilon(x)\in\{-1,1\}$, and if $y$ has zeroes, $\epsilon$ may not be constant.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I thought so too, just needed confirmation, thx

Comment: @RaunitSingh By the way, while his assertion that $y^2$ is an even function is incorrect, it could safely be removed the answer with no impact.  The issue is that his attempt has _another_ error which directly impacts its validity.  Can you find it?  (it's almost by luck that his answer is (D), which turns out to be correct)

Comment: Youtube had the "great" idea to remove the negative votes making it almost impossible to detect bad videos. The vast majority of the math videos is just clickbait and rather confusing than useful , at best good to be "entertained".

Comment: what the heck! again $y^2$ is taken to be even in another question by another instructor and arriving at the correct answer, Is it all coincidence??  (I have updated the question)

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, the channels are conflating two tests.

> If a differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = F(x)$ has a unique solution on $(-c,c)$ such that $y(0) = a$, then
>
> - $F(-x) = -F(x)$ if and only if $y(x)$ is an even function
> - $F(-x) = F(x)$ if and only if $y(x) - a$ is an odd function

> If a differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = F(x,y)$ has a unique solution on $(-c,c)$ such that $y(0) = a$, then
>
> - If $F(-x,y) = -F(x,y)$, then $y(x)$ is an even function.
> - If $F(-x,2a-y) = F(x,y)$, then $y(x)-a$ is an odd function.

The two tests are related, but definitely distinct, and while it sounds like they are using the former test based on their explanations, only the latter applies.

Answer (score -2):

We are given
$$y'=y^2-1+\cos x $$
$$y(0)=0$$
Putting $x=0$ gives
$$y'(0)=0$$
Differentiating
$$y''=2yy'-\sin x $$
Putting $x=0$ gives
$$y''(0)=0$$
Differentiating
$$y'''=2yy''+2(y')^2-\cos x $$
Putting $x=0$ gives
$$y'''(0)=-1$$
So by Taylor's theorem,
$$y(x)=y(0)+xy'(0)+\frac12x^2y''(0)+\frac16x^3y'''(0)+O(x^4) =-\frac16x^3+O(x^4) $$
and we see that $y(x)$ is strictly decreasing close to $x=0$.

Comment: The condition $y(x) = -\frac 16 x^3 + O(x^4)$ does not mean that $y$ is decreasing near 0. For instance take $y(x) = -\frac 16 x^3 + x^4\sin \left ( x^{-2} \right )$

Comment: That's very interesting - I stand corrected.
Should I delete my wrong answer?